# How can I update Calendar on my iPhone through my Xcode app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to update iCal from within my iPhone app, I believe I need to use the EventKit framework but cannot find any examples. I've found a snippet of code which uses

```
EKEvenStore *thisEvent = [EKEventStore eventWithEventStore:eventstore];
```

but it wont compile, so I am missing something. If anyone can provide an example that would really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a site which had a tutorial which did the job for me, The site is http://mobileorchard.com/ios-advanced-programming-event-kit-framework/